# ffmpeg unrecognized option "draw_mouse"

Tags: video, ffmpeg, screenshot, capture

There is ffmpeg package installed from ppa:mc3man/trusty-media.

```
ffmpeg version N-78590-g5590ab4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
```

When i try to capture screen with mouse pointer:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -report -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -framerate 25 -video_size 800x600 -i :0+0,0  -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast  -q:v 1 -s 800x600 -f matroska /tmp/test.mkv
```

ffmpeg returns an error:

```
Unrecognized option 'draw_mouse'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your command (without `-report`; it's usually way too verbose).

Answer (score 0):

Your command for ffmpeg is fine, works like a charm with default ffmpeg on Ubuntu 15.04.

The problem of `Unrecognized option 'draw_mouse'` is probably related to *"wrong"* configuration of ffmpeg on your system. You should compile ffmpeg yourself and add following options while configuring it: `--enable-gpl --enable-x11grab`, then compile ffmpeg. You can find more information about compilation of ffmpeg on Ubuntu [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Source: [FFmpeg Support Forum](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1589).